# Таймер для браузера

Tags: таймер, javascript

Нужно изменить в скрипте,чтобы цифры таймера были в начале вкладки, а не в конце.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==

defTitle=document.title;
startTime=new Date().getTime();
window.setInterval(function(){
   document.title=defTitle+' - '+Math.round((new Date().getTime()-startTime)/1000);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Нормально оформи а то не понятно

Comment: @Nikolay  Suprun, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defTitle=document.title;
startTime=new Date().getTime();
window.setInterval(function(){
    document.title=Math.round((new Date().getTime()-startTime)/1000)+' - '+defTitle;
},1000);
```

Comment: То что нужно!
Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Nikolay Suprun, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).